# Google Run Flask execution

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-run, docker-image

My goal is to run my own APIs on google cloud using their Run service.

I built a simple flask application as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/python) and created the container image as described in the tutorial.

The exact code I used is the following:

```
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def helloworld():
    print("1")
    return "worked"

print(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("0")
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
print("0.5")
```

Now when I run this code locally the result is different to when I run it on google cloud.

1. the `__name__` variable is `main` when run in the cloud. Executed locally, its the expected `__main__`. Hence the if clause is false and not executed.
2. But surprisingly, the helloworld function is still executed, and the rest of the code is also run again.

So the output in the logs from google cloud run looks like this:

```
main
0.5
1
main
0.5
```

And when I execute it on my laptop:

```
__main__
0
1
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install flask gunicorn

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Can someone explain to my why this is? Is this a bug or a mistake from me?

I am new to using cloud services and docker images. Would really appreciate if someone could help me.
Thank you in advance.

And please let me know if the question is unclear.

Edit: Added the dockerfile

Comment: Include your Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I added the Dockerfile

Comment: You are using two web servers in your code/container. Flask and Gunicorn. Your code is working in the cloud because the **__name__** section is not using the Flask web server.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you. Ill have to look more into what exactly Gunicorn and Flask does. But I guess hats why it still works in google cloud when I remove the app.run() part correct? And app.route("/") is just here so a function is actually executed when there is a call for the specified URL?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is because you most likely built the container with gunicorn as below in the Dockerfile below:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

This is telling gunicorn to import the app variable from the main.py file, hence **name** will always be set to main in that file.

From the documentation:

> This code responds to requests with our "Hello World" greeting. HTTP
> handling is done by a Gunicorn web server in the container. When
> directly invoked for local use, this code creates a basic web server
> that listens on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.